# hg diff two different files from a certain revision

Tags: mercurial, diff

I want to see the difference between `filea` and `fileb` as of rev1234, because `fileb` appears to have been a fork-and-change-and-thereafter-run-two-versions-of-one-library, without a super informative commit message.

I tried `hg diff -r 1234 filea fileb`, but that just shows me two diffs:

1. that between `filea` as of rev1234 and its current version, and
2. that between `fileb` as of rev1234 and *its* current version

I want ONE diff, between `filea` as of rev1234 and `fileb` as of rev1234.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that *both* files are present in r1234?

If r1234 is not your current working dir state, update your working directory to r1234 beforehand: `hg update -r1234`
Then you do not need any mercurial command but the normal diff command:
`diff fileA fileB`.  When you're done, `hg up` again to return to normal.

Comment: Yes, both are present as of r1234.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's roundabout, but you can create a directory, export just those two files from that revision, and then compare them:

```
mkdir tempdiff
hg archive -r 1234 -I filea -I fileb tempdiff/
diff tempdiff/filea tempdiff/fileb
rm -r tempdiff
```

A one-command method would be nice, though.